# Can I run "Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1" after installing "Azure Service Fabric"?

Tags: servicebus, azure-service-fabric

My Message Broker service from *"Service bus for Windows Server 1.1"* was running ok until I installed *"Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK Preview - 1.4.187"*.

After installing *Service Fabric*, my "Service Bus Message Broker" service remains in the status: StartPending.

I guess that, with the installation of Service *Fabric*, I replaced/updated the "Windows Fabric" that Service *Bus* runs on and that Service *Bus* cannot run on the newer *Fabric*. Is this true? Are there plans to get these two to work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't supported. Service Bus on Win Server runs on an old  version of Service Fabric (as you can tell by the old Windows naming convention) which isn't compatible with the current version.

Comment: Good to know there is a hard dependency.